# r- I am not to display the labels when hover on the highcharter objects

Tags: r, highcharts

I am able to display data labels on hover on the highcharter object. I have added my code in this post can you suggest change and make it correct. also refer to image that i am attacting to this post for query:

[image]

enter code here:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(highcharter)
DF<-Tooltip_Demo
dataframe<-data.frame(Year=DF$Year,Country=DF$Country,City=DF$City,Discount=DF$Discount,
Sales_amount=DF$Sales_amount,Profit=DF$Profit)
df_table<-tbl_df(dataframe)
df_table
gp <- df_table %>%
arrange(desc(Year)) %>%
distinct(Country, .keep_all = TRUE)
gp2 <- df_table %>%
select(Country, Year,Discount, Sales_amount, Profit) %>%
nest(-Country) %>%
mutate(
data = map(data, mutate_mapping, hcaes(x = Year, y = Profit), drop = TRUE),
data = map(data, list_parse)
) %>%
rename(ttdata = data)
gptot <- left_join(gp,gp2,by="Country")
hchart(
 gptot,
 "point",
 hcaes(Discount,Sales_amount,name = City,size = Profit,group = Country, name = City)

 )  %>%
  hc_xAxis(labels=list(format ='(value) %')) %>%
  hc_yAxis(type = "logarithmic") %>%

  hc_tooltip(useHTML = TRUE, headerFormat = "<b>{point.key}</b>", pointFormatter = 
  tooltip_chart(accesor = "ttdata",hc_opts = list(xAxis = list(type = "Category"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your `pointFormatter`. It can be done in Highcharter like this:

```
hc_tooltip(pointFormatter = JS("function(){/* function body goes here*/}")
```

Depending on the information you want to display on the tooltip, you need to create your own function.

**JS Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c295tbja/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter